# 英語が残っている: カスタムフィルタ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

*サイトではカスタムフィルタとカスタムフィルターの2つが両方使われていますが、そこは目をつぶって。*

画面右メニュー「カスタムフィルタを作成」の移動先ページに英語が多数残っています。

[image: スクリーンショット]

並び替え: 「Recent activity」「Most votes」「Most frequent」「Bounty ending soon」
タグ付けされた: 「The following tags:」とその下のプレースホルダー
上のタブ「More」
「お礼」タブを選んだ時の「0 questions with bounties」
「More」内「未回答(フォロー中のタグ)」を選んだ時の「Questions with my tags」

Comment: https://ja.traducir.win/ から翻訳を投稿できます :)

Answer (score 2):

該当箇所含め「カスタムフィルタ」関連の文字列は最近追加されたのでいくつかは翻訳を進めていて、
訳に迷っていた部分をあえて残していましたが、先ほど残りも翻訳を追加してみました。
しばらく時間をおけば反映されると思うのでお待ちください。

なお、プレースホルダ内の「python or javascript」となっている部分については、特別な変数に入った値が反映されるようなので、「python または javascript」の様には翻訳できなさそうです。